# LDAP connection could not be established using PHP LDAP Extention

Tags: c#, php, asp.net, ldap

I have tried to connect ldap server using PHP ldap_connection which is not working and getting false in ldap_binding. I have tried the same connection using Asp.net console app using PrincipalContext which works fine. I dont know what im doing wrong, could you please some one help to resolve the issue. Both code run in same machine and same development environment setting.

```
//C# Code
PrincipalContext pc = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "domainname");               
isValid = pc.ValidateCredentials("Username", "Pass");

;PHP Code
$adServer = "ldap://domainname";
$ldap = ldap_connect($adServer) or die("Could not connect to LDAP server.");
$bind = ldap_bind($ldap, "domainname\\username", "password");
```

error:
PHP Warning:  ldap_bind(): Unable to bind to server: Can't contact LDAP server

Comment: I'm not an ldap expert, but what is happening? Getting fatal errors? Bind only returns true/false, why the `@` operator? Using this operator will hide any potentially helpful errors. I do believe that there is a ldap extension that must be enabled. At the command line, if you run: `php -m`, is ldap in the output of modules? Other than that, see if the [info here](https://riptutorial.com/ldap/example/19797/setting-up-php-to-work-with-ldap) could help.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I have checked php -m and LDAP module listed there. Yes im getting false in ldap_binding function.